# Typescript compilation through Serverless failing

Tags: typescript, serverless-framework

I have a Typescript-based Lambda function that compiles fine with `tsc` but when I attempt to deploy through Serverless, the Typescript complication fails with the following error:

```
Serverless: Running "serverless" installed locally (in service node_modules)
Serverless: Compiling with Typescript...
Serverless: Using local tsconfig.json
Serverless: Warning: "rootDir" from local tsconfig.json is overriden
Cannot locate handler - account. not found
 
  Error --------------------------------------------------
 
  Error: Typescript compilation failed. Please ensure handlers exists with ext .ts or .js
      at /Users/bob/Development/service-account/node_modules/serverless-plugin-typescript/src/typescript.ts:69:13
```

The relevant chunks of `account.ts` code are:

```js
import { APIGatewayProxyHandler, APIGatewayEvent, Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import 'source-map-support/register';

export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context): Promise<any> => {
    console.debug(`event: ${JSON.stringify(event, null, 1)}`);
    console.debug(`context: ${JSON.stringify(context, null, 1)}`);
...
}
```

The relevant sections of the serverless.yml file are:

```yaml
plugins:
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-webpack

service: accounts

custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true

functions:
  account:
    handler: account.handler
...
```

The tsconfig.json is rather standard:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

The directory tree looks like this:

```
config <dir>
dist <dir>
node_modules <dir>
src <dir>
  account.ts
swagger <dir>
package.json
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
serverless.yml
```

Thoughts on what I am missing on connecting all the dots to get this working within Serverless?

Comment: Could you post the directory tree from your project root and below?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to provide the relative path to the handler, this should work

```yaml
functions:
  account:
    handler: "./src/account.handler"
```

You may choose to omit `./` and `handler: "src/account.handler"` should also work.

Comment: Thank you for that, that is not something I would have thought of.  I would have believed that the rootDir would have taken care of that.  I have moved on to the following error:   Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
 
  The webpack plugin could not find the configuration file at: /Users/bob/Development/service-account/.build/webpack.config.js

Comment: The list of files in your question is missing `webpack.config.js`, normally it gets created when you set up a new project using the command: `sls create --template aws-nodejs-typescript`

Comment: It is there, I just misnamed it. I am thinking it is related to: https://github.com/prisma-labs/serverless-plugin-typescript/issues/219

Comment: . is not necessary but the correct path yes !!!